# Count Function after query in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have written some query and I wanted to know the number of rows or total rows count. Is there a "count" function that can be applied on top of the query?

My query is like:

```
select customer_id, sum(amount)
from payment
group by customer_id having sum(amount)>100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `count()` as a window function, like in

```
SELECT *,
       count(*) OVER () AS total_count
FROM (SELECT customer_id,
             sum(amount)
      FROM payment
      GROUP BY customer_id HAVING sum(amount)>100) AS q;
```

That will return the total count in an additional column.

Comment: There is no need for the subquery. COUNT() can be used as the 3d column in the main query.

Comment: @forpas I am trying to show a general principle. You are right in this case, but if the query contains `LIMIT` or `OFFSET`, a subquery would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery or CTE:

```
select count(*)
from (select customer_id, sum(amount)
      from payment
      group by customer_id
      having sum(amount)>100
     ) c;
```